# How to style only the background image in a div using CSS and not the content between the div tags?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

I have an Angular application where I am using a common background image throughout the application. I have placed this image using css and div tags which enclose my router-outlet and now want to style the image by changing the opacity. How can I do so without the styling also effecting everything enclosed by this div tag? There is no css property for background opacity.

HTML

```
<app-nav-bar *ngIf="auth.loggedIn()"></app-nav-bar>
<div class="background">
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.background {
background-image: url('/assets/imgs/contour.jpg');
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `:after` or `:before` pseudo element.

In this case your CSS would become something like this:

```
.background:after {
  content: "";
  background-image: url('/assets/imgs/contour.jpg');
  opacity: 0.2;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

Here, you can change the `opacity` to whatever you need.

Here's a JSFiddle demonstrating this:
https://jsfiddle.net/9frz56xc/